# Session ID Process repeating Thousands of times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, taskmanager

[image]

I have this process in the Task Manager that seems to repeat itself over 2000 times. I am unsure what it is and why it is doing it, but it is causing performance issues and i was hoping someone would be able to shine a light on what this means. It is a T-Sql JobStep, but it seems to be sleeping or stuck. It just sits in there and does nothing. If you need more info please ask and i will do my best to provide you with the information necessary

Comment: The description mentions a SQL Agent job. Why don't you go to the next step and investigate that job. Here is a guide to finding it. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1479243-391-1.aspx Also is that user used for anything in particular? Maybe a restart of SQL Agent will fix it but first you should find the root cause

Comment: could it be a back up job tat is failing?
Check you sqlServer machine event log.